# If and elif in Python for good programming practices

Tags: python, if-statement

Hello there I'm currently trying to get a good grasp of the if, elif, else structure in Python. I'm trying some weird combinations in python having a test program to know the output in this if, if, elif, elif, else code. However I'm getting weird results such as this

```
input = raw_input('Please enter the required digit: ')
intput = int(input)

if intput == 0:
    print 'if1'

if intput == 1:
    print 'if2'
elif intput == 0:
    print 'elif1'
elif intput == 1:
    print 'elif2'
else:
    print 'else'
```

if I in put 1 it will print "if2", I thought that it will also print "elif2" and other shenanigans when I try to change the "intput == n" code. So my question is do I have to stick to the if,elif, elif, .... n * elifs, else method which seems to me working alright than working with the wacky if,if.... n * ifs, elif, elif, ...n* elifs, else.

Thanks

Comment: `elif's` are only evaluated if the preceding `if/elif` statement is `False`, if you had all if statements then they would all be evaluated, if none are `True` then the `else` statement will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the insight will tinker with it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The elif tree is designed such that at anywhere along if one of the statement turns out to be `True`, the rest of the `elif`s will not be evaluated.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.udemy.com/blog/python-if-else/) that might help you understand `if else` better.

Answer (score 0):

this may be more clear to understand:

```
if input == 0:
    print "if1"

switch(input):
    case 1:
        print "if2"
        break
    case 0:
        print "elif1"
        break
    case 1:
        print "elif2"
        break
    default:
        print "else"
        break
```

of course, the code does not work.